# Machine Arithmetic and Smearing: addition of a large an small number

Tags: math, binary, precision

So to 10000 one will add the value 1/10000 10000times. Logically this gives 10001.
However, due to smearing this does not occur which stems from storage limitations. The result is 10000.999999992928. 
I have located where the smearing occurs, which is in the second addition:

```
1:  10000.0001
2:  10000.000199999999
3:  10000.000299999998
4:  10000.000399999997
etc...
```

However, grasping why the smearing occurred is where the struggle lies.
I wrote code to generate floating point binary numbers to see whether smearing occurred here

```
So 10000 = 10011100010000 or 1.001110001*10**13 while

0.0001= 0.00000000000001101001 or 

1.1010001101101110001011101011000111000100001100101101*2**(-14)

then 10000.0001 = 10011100010000.00000000000001101001
```

Now the smearing occurs in the next addition. Does it have to do with mantissa size? Why does it only occur in this step as well? Just interested to know. I am going to add all the 1/10000 first and then add it to the 10000 to avoid smaering.

Comment: You might be better off finding a good general guide to floating-point representations.  I'd recommend [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic* by David Goldberg](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), or, for a gentler ride, the [*Floating-Point Guide* web site](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The small "smearing" error for a single addition can be computed exactly as

```
a=10000; b=0.0001
err = ((a+b)-a)-b
print "err=",err

>>> err= -7.07223084891e-13
```

The rounding error of an addition is of size `(abs(a)+abs(b))*mu/2` or around `1e4 * 1e-16 = 1e-12`, which nicely fits the computed result.
In general you also have to test the expression `((a+b)-b)-a`, but one of them is always zero, here the latter one.

And indeed this single step error accumulated over all the steps already gives the observed result, secondary errors relating to the slow increase in the sum as first term in each addition having a much lower impact.

```
print err*10000
>>> -7.072230848908026e-09
print 10001+err*10000
>>> 10000.999999992928
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that `1/10000` i.e. `0.0001` cannot be encoded exactly as a machine float value (see the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standard), since `10000` is not a power of 2. Also `1/10 = 0.1` cannot be encoded as machine float, so you will experience phanomena like `0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 > 0.3`.

When computing with double precision (64 bit) the following holds:

```
1.0001 - 1 < 0.0001
10000.0001 + 9999*0.0001 == 10001
```

So I assume you are computing with single precision (32 bit)?